IQuestion about 50/50 beam splitter for single photons and bunched photons
This is my first post to Physics Stack Exchange.
I was trying to understand a research paper that involves self-interference of single photons...
https://www.nature.com/articles/s41598-023-28264-1
My question for this forum does not involve the results or conclusions of the paper. Instead, I have a question about just one small part of the experimental set up and the authors' interpretation of that one part.
If I understand the paper correctly, the authors wished to create a beam of single photons (photons spaced far enough apart in the beam so that there is no significant overlap between the photons). To do this, the authors sent a laser beam through an attentuator (see my figure, below).

To see if the photons in the attenuated beam were actually single photons, the beam was sent into a 50/50 beam splitter, with photon detector D1 monitoring one of the beam splitter's output beams and detector D2 monitoring the other output beam of the beam splitter. Both detectors sent their "clicks" to a coincidence counter (not shown in my figure).
My understanding of how a 50/50 beam splitter works is this: Each individual photon that arrives at the beam splitter has a 50% probability of making D1 click and a 50% probability of making D2 click. But no single individual photon can make a coincidence (both detectors clicking simultaneously). So if no coincidences were found in the experiment that would indicate that the authors had created a beam of single photons.
The authors reported that only about 1% of the clicks were coincidence clicks. They therefore concluded that only about 1% of the photons in the beam were "bunched" (two photons traveling together in the beam) and thus 99% of the photons in the beam must be single photons.
This conclusion is where my confusion and question arises. It seems to me that when 2 bunched photons (2 photons traveling together) arrive at the beam splitter only half of the time will that result in a coincidence click. The other half of the time, both photons will either both go to D1 or D2 and thus only a single click (not a coincidence double click) will occur. So it seems to me that the authors should have concluded that 2% of the photons in the beam were bunched, based on their 1% coincidence click rate.
Am I misunderstanding something about the authors' experiment (such as how 50/50 beam splitters work) or did the authors make a mistake in saying that there were 1% bunched photons in the beam rather than 2%?

Your reasoning is correct.

Thank you, @flippiefanus. Do you feel that the authors' overall conclusions of the paper are correct?

@flippiefanus That 99% of the time a single photon will always choose either to be completely reflected or completely refracted does imply the photon has more internal "structure" than an arbitrary electromagnetic wave ripple, since arbitrary EM wave ripples can certainly be split like a wave by crystal barriers, correct? How do we decide if we are generating a single "photon" or a single "electromagnetic ripple"?

@James Do you perhaps want to pose that as a question on this site?

@flippiefanus I think I understand this a little better now: electromagnetic ripples are any unstructured ripples that exist in the $E$ and $B$ field. They disperse and evolve over time purely according to Maxwell equations. Photons are non-dispersive wave packets, and as such they have special properties not governed by the regular Maxwell equations (for unstructured em ripples), these extra properties are bestowed by their non-dispersive structure.

@James, that could be a rather misleading way to think of photons. Even a single photon can disperse while it propagates. It is just that when you measure it, you get the whole photon despite the dispersion.

@flippiefanus if a photon disperses even a minuscule amount as it travels, how does a photon from a distant galaxy 13 billion years ago remain a photon that we can detect today?

@James, that is the whole reason for the so-called measurement problem. I have a way to understand it, but it needs more space than a comment can provide to explain.

@flippiefanus thank you. I do hope someone asks that question, I would rather avoid any drama :)
